# oracle sql - how to prepare a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have got in the DB data like you can see below (additional info about dates: date in valid_from is included, date in valid_to is excluded)

| obj_number | status | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1001 | active | 01.01.2018 | 01.01.2019 |
| A1001 | pending | 01.01.2019 | 31.03.2019 |
| A1001 | pending | 31.03.2019 | 30.06.2019 |
| A1001 | pending | 30.06.2019 | 31.12.2019 |
| A1001 | active | 31.12.2019 | 31.12.2020 |
| A1001 | active | 31.12.2020 |  |

I have to merge the data, when status changes, but valid_from should be from the oldest record and valid_to should be from the newest record. The result from the data you can see above should be like you can see below

| obj_number | status | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1001 | active | 01.01.2018 | 01.01.2019 |
| A1001 | pending | 01.01.2019 | 31.12.2019 |
| A1001 | active | 31.12.2019 |  |

how to prepare a sql query to achieve it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun way to do it (assuming you are on oracle 12c+):

```
select *
from tt
match_recognize (
  partition by
    obj_number
  order by
    valid_from
  measures
    init.status as status,
    first(valid_from) as valid_from,
    last(valid_to) as valid_to
  one row per match
  pattern (init same_status*)
  define
    same_status as status = prev(status)
)
;
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=71e2ceb5c0eafaed39fff85987cb58e4)

Using [MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8957) we can

> Logically partition and order the data that is used in the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause with its PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses.

> Define patterns of rows to seek using the PATTERN clause of the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause. These patterns use regular expression syntax, a powerful and expressive feature, applied to the pattern variables you define.

> Specify the logical conditions required to map a row to a row pattern variable in the DEFINE clause.

> Define measures, which are expressions usable in other parts of the SQL query, in the MEASURES clause.

So how does it work?

1. we `partition by` obj_number
2. `order by` rows inside the partitions using valid_from
3. define what columns we want to see using `measures`
4. define what we want to match using `pattern`, in this case we take a row and then we try to match as many *same_status* rows as possible (`*` is the 0-many repetition symbol as in regular expressions)
5. `define` what *same_status* means, in this case the row is *same_status* if it has the same status as the previous row
6. in the measures we select *valid_from* from the first row in the match and *valid_to* from the last row of the match

Comment: Petr, amazing solution !!! It works correctly. To be honest now I have to spend some time to understand how it works and how to use match_recognize

Comment: Maybe you'll find [this video](https://youtu.be/BHCzce5Ls4Y) hepful, I find it to be a great introduction to the topic

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  Assuming there are no gaps on adjacent, the difference of `row_number()`s is the simplest approach:

```
select obj_number, status, min(valid_from),
       (case when count(*) = count(valid_to)
             then max(valid_to)
        end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by obj_number) order by valid_from) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by obj_number, status order by valid_from) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by obj_number, status, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Note the extra logic to handle `NULL` values for `valid_to`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. After small changes it works ! (please add comma after t.* and delete reduntant bracket from line 6 and 7 for other users, that will read it). It should looks like this: select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by obj_number order by valid_from) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by obj_number, status order by valid_from) as seqnum

Answer (score 1):

You need to check `status` and also dates (if not overlapping then different row should be generated for same consecutive status) so you can use the `lag` and `sum` analytical function along with the group by as follows:

```
select obj_number, status, min(valid_from) as valid_from, 
       case when count(case when valid_to is null then 1 end) = 0 
            then max(valid_to) 
       end as valid_to
From
(select t.*,
       sum(case when lgtodt >= valid_from then 0 else 1 end) 
          over (partition by obj_number, status order by valid_from) as sm
  from
(select t.*,
       lag(valid_to) over (partition by obj_number, status order by valid_from) as lgtodt
  from your_table t) t ) t
group by obj_number, status, sm
```

Comment: interesting solution, but dates in the merged rows are incorrect (valid to is from the same record instead of the last merged record)

Comment: Ok, Updated the answer. Check now.

Comment: thanks for the update - now it works correctly !!!  (please edit the query and add from between 4th and 5th line to be clear for other people)